# One to one composition vs. one to one association

Tags: cuba-platform

I have a customer with an address. The address should be deleted if the customer will be deleted. In my opinion it is a composition. But compositions in cuba are only one to many.

I solved it with in one to one association and the cascade type ALL:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
protected address
```

Is this the way I have to go?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, currently the `@Composition` annotation affects only the way how editors work for one-to-many relationships. Editing of one-to-one relationships will be covered in a future release, it's on our roadmap.

For cascade deletion we recomend the following approach:

- If the master entity implements `SoftDelete`, use `@OnDelete(DeletePolicy.CASCADE)` annotation on the detail attribute
- Otherwise, use `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your foreign key definition - it can be added manually to init/update scripts

Comment: when it will be possible to use one-to-one relationships in cuba platform?

Comment: @bresche You can use one-to-one association. Could you explain what you need and what does not work for you? Your initial question is about cascaded deletion, and I've offered the solutions.